# How many shuffles

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, card-games, abstract-algebra

A riffle shuffle is a type of shuffle where the deck is split into two partitions and the partitions are then spliced back together to create a new shuffled deck.

The cards are spliced together in such a way that cards maintain their relative order *within the partition they are a member of*.  For example, if card **A** is before card **B** in the deck and cards **A** and **B** are in the same partition, card **A** must be before card **B** in the final result, even if the number of cards between them has increased.  If **A** and **B** are in different partitions, they can be in any order, regardless of their starting order, in the final result.

Each riffle shuffle can then be viewed as a permutation of the original deck of cards.  For example the permutation

```
1,2,3 -> 1,3,2
```

is a riffle shuffle.  If you split the deck like so

```
1, 2 | 3
```

we see that every card in `1,3,2` has the same relative order to every other card in it's partition.  `2` is still after `1`.

On the other hand the following permutation is *not* a riffle shuffle.

```
1,2,3 -> 3,2,1
```

We can see this because for all the two (non-trivial) partitions

```
1, 2 | 3
1 | 2, 3
```

there is a pair of cards that do not maintain their relative orderings.  In the first partition `1` and `2` change their ordering, while in the second partition `2` and `3` change their ordering.

However we do see that `3, 2, 1` can be made by composing two riffle shuffles,

```
1, 3, 2 + 2, 3, 1 = 3, 2, 1
```

In fact a pretty simple fact to be proven is that *any* permutation can be made my combining some number of riffle shuffle permutations.

## Task

Your task is to make a program or function that takes a permutation (of size **N**) as input and outputs the smallest number of riffle shuffle permutations (of size **N**) that can be combined to form the input permutation.  You do not need to output the riffle shuffles themselves just how many there are.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

You may output either 1 or 0 for an identity permutation.

## Test Cases

```
1,3,2 -> 1
3,2,1 -> 2
3,1,2,4 -> 1
2,3,4,1 -> 1
4,3,2,1 -> 2
```

Comment: So, will we be seeing RiffleSort algorithms soon?

Comment: Shouldn't `4,3,2,1` be `2`?
First we split in the middle and gain `3,1,4,2` and then we split in the middle again and use the same permutation

Comment: @HalvardHummel That's correct.  I'll have to find the issue with my reference implementation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 255 bytes

Checks all possible riffles up to the length of the list (maximum number required), so it is very slow for larger input. Could also probably be golfed quite a bit.

```python
lambda x:f(range(1,len(x)+1),x)
f=lambda x,y,i=0:x==y and i or i<len(x)and min(f(q,y,i+1)for a in range(1,len(x))for q in g(x[:a],x[a:]))or i
g=lambda x,y:(x or y)and[[v]+q for v in x[:1]for q in g(x[1:],y)]+[[v]+q for v in y[:1]for q in g(x,y[1:])]or[[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NbsMgEITP4Sk4gryH4viEypOQVUUbO0ZK8B@J4OldNq3bJCd2dr@ZYcyxH8J@7c1hPbvL59HxpDsxu3BqhYJzG0SSlZKQJOvMRkAGb950MiZzF47c82Hm/v2HpsXFB9GJibhi7srVcR/4c@x9P9H@JJLVDiFZp1FKCmOnhzYtEjVkyrb2htXEyXsjb3EqfEpSGiFLrF7J/EpCJlbiMFuLuMZ2iR9fbmkXbrhlO2sV7KFGUAikykxjvSlVdPN3rQvbkPjVDTzwyBgV@zBeI/DhGstLn/iv1Gw3zj5E0Ys7JTdMrt8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>206</s> ... 185 bytes

```
import StdEnv
f=flatten
$a b#[c:d]=b
|a>[]#[u:v]=a
=[a++b,b++a:f[[[u,c:e],[c,u:e]]\\e<- $v d]]=[b]
@l#i=length l
=hd[n\\n<-[0..],e<-iter n(f o map(uncurry$o splitAt(i/2)))[[1..i]]|l==e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY89b4MwFAB3/4onwQDC0Cb9GFBcpVI7VOqW8fEGY0xiyRgENlKk/Pa6nm654U5ZLV2c5iFYDZM0LpppmVcPFz98u52NYrTSe@1YLqHPULUDiZ495AdShqHdSUgmUFZVz/uqku2IiIGrVhNHxUMidZ0@1ZDvMBAJ7ImdbWaE1e7qb2CZuA3ous6danxuGuJJNl6v4IoR5tS0FMGpsK73fIZtscZ/@sI8HcuyRDw0jSF6WCE0xYuXKVzAGfDIX/g7P/BX/kbxT6WH6xbrn9/4dXdyMmr7Bw)

Generates every possible outcome of shuffling `n` times, and checks if the list is a member.
While this is a horribly inefficient way to solve the problem, this code is *particularly slow* due to its use of list comprehensions instead of composition, which heavily limits any elementary graph reduction, and results in a spectacular showcase of Clean's garbage collector.

**Ungolfed:**

```
import StdEnv
shuffle [] l
    = [l]
shuffle [a: b] [c: d]
    = [[a: b]++[c: d], [c: d]++[a: b]: flatten [
        [[a, c: e], [c, a: e]]
        \\ e <- shuffle b d
        ]]
numReq l
    = until cond ((+)1) 0
where
    cond n 
        = let
            mapper
                = map (uncurry shuffle o splitAt (length l/2))
            options
                = iter n (removeDup o flatten o mapper) [[1..length l]]
        in isMember l options
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLbsIwELzzFXNMhKGFPg5ROVSih0rtpRxDDiZZwJIfqWNT8fNNl0DSInVP3pmd2dW41CRta1wVNcFIZVtlaucDVqF6sYdRs4/bLVN5AT0C1wK5Ln5hmWFTIC8zVEXPn8Hx@IyKC8t9h2fYahkCWeSd4FQsEeAp6qYF5OlZDPR6DcLTBP3WDaqB4zEbzQd9DvdFG5RG6WyFJBmnsxS3o689eer4DrcY9AtoCkN3KiPrmvwVdB5kAkm0ZfT@ONzi0NRaheeARJPdhT30zTxNr@SuDsrZ5h9LFcjzNYkn4w60jDX79fG4yyUpxzObTnv3P7koC9W8k9mwie63tKsg@f8WuMSSz8WdeBQzcS8eiva7ZPtd005e39rl0UqjyuYH)